# Ruby/Rails Debugging: Break when a value of an object/variable changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

In Ruby on Rails while debugging is there any way where we can ask the debugger to break the execution as soon as a value at specific memory location or the value of a variable/object changes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much of a break in execution do you want?

If the variable is set from outside the instance, then it will be being accessed via some method. You could overwrite such a method just for this purpose.

```
# define
class Foo
  def bar
    @bar ||= 'default'
  end

  def bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end

# overwrite
class Foo
  def bar=(value)
    super
    abort("Message goes here")
  end
end
```

Comment: In my case I don't know where the value is changing. i.e. i don't know about the exact function/location of the code where the change happening. So I wanted to use such functionality of debugger ( if available ) that whenever that value changes the debugger breaks execution and i will be able to locate that particular piece of code.

Comment: This is just an indication of a strategy for finding where the change is being called from. If it is internal to the instance, you could ensure all access to the variable goes though the getter/setter methods. If it is from an external call, then a similar line of reasoning applies. If, however, the data is being changed with a bulk update of the db table, then all bets are off.